# Designing such a layout using html & css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout like this with html & css for thumbnail listing.
[image]

I want to fill a `DIV` with thumbnails & exclude a portion of that `DIV` from content & fill it with some other content;
Is it possible? How?

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If you build it carefully, and all your thumbnails have the same dimensions, and your upper-right-other-content can be a sibling of the thumbnails, I think you can do it with floats and a few extra elements to create the borders as show.  Of course, CSS tables may do the trick also.

Comment: @Vucko: I tried absolute positioning of smaller div in the upper right; but the thumbnails go behind it!

Comment: @4r1y4n it that is the problem then use `z-index`.

Comment: @Vucko: and then the thumbnails will hide behind the upper right DIV!

Comment: @4r1y4n yes, you have to give to all elements an _aboslute_ value. In your case, `float` or `display:inline-block` is the answer, without using `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a floating layout. You could `float:left;` on everything in CSS, `clear:left;` on the 7th small div. Note that you may need to hold open the div that you're putting this HTML inside. For backward compatibility I use an empty div at the bottom and `clear:left;` on it. You may consider a background image on the larger div to the right to create that border effect.